# How to combine different event triggers

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers

I am new to jQuery and hope someone can help me with this.

I have a JS function that is triggered by various elements / classes with the difference that for some of them the event is triggered by a click and for others on keyup etc.

So far I have the following as an example which works as intended but I was wondering if there is a way to **combine these as the only difference here is the trigger (click, keyup etc.)** and to avoid duplicating code.

If there are any other suggestions to write this different please let me know as well.

**My jQuery (example):**

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.calcMinus, .calcPlus', function(e){
    var row = $(e.target);
    $(row).closest('table').find('td.calcSum').each(function(index){
        calculateSums(row, index);
    });
});
$(document).on('click', '.trAdd, .trDelete, .trDown, .trUp', function(e){
    var row = $(e.target);
    $(row).closest('table').find('td.calcSum').each(function(index){
        calculateSums(row, index);
    });
});
// ...
```

**My JS function:**

```
function calculateSums(row, index){
   // do stuff
}
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.calcMinus, .calcPlus', combined);
$(document).on('click keyup', '.trAdd, .trDelete, .trDown, .trUp', combined);

function combined(e){
    var row = $(e.target);
    $(row).closest('table').find('td.calcSum').each(function(index){
        calculateSums(row, index);
    });
}
```

Comment: if the downvote was because of `e` I corrected my answer

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thanks for the correction. Is it because `event` would not have worked?

Comment: No - I edited because you didn't include the `e` parameter in the `combined()` function's argument list.

Comment: @AmmarCSE I don't think `event` is present in every browser - best to stick with the one jQuery passes you, especially since it's normalised all the info on it etc.

Comment: While we're perfecting the answer - could also drop `$()` from around either `e.target` or `row`...

Comment: @JamesThorpe `event` as a keyword is fine to use, and would have caused no issues.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, ah I see now. I thought `event` was a default object in handlers but I guess its not supported against all browsers. Thanks Rory, James

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Really?  ok - that's news to me!

Comment: Thanks, All for this - that's very helpful !

Comment: @AmmarCSE: One last question on this, can I still give the function a name here (like "myFunction") or do I have to stick with combined in this case ? Sorry if this is a beginner question.

Comment: @keewee279, you can give it any name you want as long as it has a name

Comment: Perfect - I thought so. :) Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

Extract the code from your event handler to a function, and call that from both of your existing handlers:

```
function handleEvent(row) {
    $(row).closest('table').find('td.calcSum').each(function(index){
        calculateSums(row, index);
    })
}

$(document).on('keyup', '.calcMinus, .calcPlus', function(e){
    handleEvent($(e.target));
});
$(document).on('click', '.trAdd, .trDelete, .trDown, .trUp', function(e){
    handleEvent($(e.target));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! I already had my function code separate, just not all of it so this definitely helps. :)